# Flutter.dev SharedPreferences questions

Tags: flutter, sharedpreferences

Here is small part of the SharedPreferences example provided by Flutter.dev that I have problem with:

Full example code here: https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/persistence/key-value

```
  int _counter = 0;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _loadCounter();
  }

  //Loading counter value on start
  _loadCounter() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance(); // <-------------- 1
    setState(() {
      _counter = (prefs.getInt('counter') ?? 0);
    });
  }

  //Incrementing counter after click
  _incrementCounter() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance(); // <-------------- 1
    setState(() {
      _counter = (prefs.getInt('counter') ?? 0) + 1; // <------------------------------ 2
      prefs.setInt('counter', _counter); // <------------------------------------------ 3
    });
  }
```

I have 3 questions about this examples:

1. Isn't it better to make the `prefs` variable global? It would increase memory usage, but wouldn't it increase performance? If not global, every time we are tapping the button (to increment the counter) it has to declare the variable and assign it and since it's asynchronous, I think it slows down performance even more.
2. Every time we tap the button, the function `_incrementCounter` is called, it retrieves the value of `_counter` from file, why? The `_counter` variable is global, I don't think there's a need for `prefs.getInt('counter')` and that line should be simply `_counter++`;
3. Isn't it better to move this line out of the `setState` function? Because from the Flutter Dev Docs:

> Generally it is recommended that the setState method only be used to wrap the actual changes to the state, not any computation that might be associated with the change. https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/setState.html

I'm a newbie Flutter learner, I needed to ask this question so I can better understand everthing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The flutter docs are aimed for people who are just starting out in programming. They couldn't overwhelm you with many different things that you would have to take consideration for. The beginner part of flutter docs usually don't show the best practices in flutter and programming in general. You are correct with three of your answers.

1. Yes, it is better to declare it as a global variable but only to the class that is using it. For example, it would be better to declare `SharedPreferences _prefs` on top and `_prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance() inside _loadCounter()`.
   Take note that the _ keyword will mark the variable as private.
2. You are correct here. It is unnecessary and you could replace it with `_counter++`
3. It would be better to move this below `setState()` so that the your screen will rebuild without waiting for `prefs.setInt('counter', _counter);` to finish.

Comment: Try learning state management as well: https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/options . Instead of rebuilding your whole ui just to update on simple change, you will rebuild only the widget that needs to get changed.